# Invalid `Podfile` file: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - flutter_module⁩/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I am integrating flutter module in the iOS app and while installing the pod, I am getting this error.

Below is the code in podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FlutteriOSApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FlutteriOSApp

  target 'FlutteriOSAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'FlutteriOSAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

flutter_application_path = 'flutter_module⁩/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb'
eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path)), binding)

end
```

I also tried with

```
flutter_application_path = 'flutter_module'
  eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)
```

Also, the file exists at

```
flutter_module⁩/.ios/Flutter/podhelper.rb
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. I deleted podfile and reinitialized pod in the project directory and also changing

```
flutter_application_path = 'flutter_module'
```

to

```
flutter_application_path = 'flutter_module/'
```

> **Notice the '/' at last.**

Now after pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `flutter_module/.ios/Flutter/engine`
Fetching podspec for `FlutterPluginRegistrant` from `flutter_module/.ios/Flutter/FlutterPluginRegistrant`
Downloading dependencies
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing FlutterPluginRegistrant (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `12.2` on target `FlutteriOSApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Answer (score 2):

i just used these commands:

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter precache

cd ios

pod install
```

i hope this work for you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Hello After Searching a lot that's what has worked for me -> "This my Pod file Below "

[image]